# Area enclosed by a circle and leminscate

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

> Find the area enclosed by a circle $r=4\sin\theta$ and out of $r^2=8\cos 2\theta$

[image]

I have tried the following integral $\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{\sqrt{8\cos2\theta}}^{4\sin\theta}dr d\theta+\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{\sqrt{8\cos2\theta}}^{4\sin\theta}dr d\theta$ but it seems to be wrong

Comment: Any reason you're using double integrals for this?

Comment: Add an $r$ to have $rdrd\theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider full circle and individual parts *separately*, which are easy. There is no real need to lump them into a single integral in situations of area overlaps  like here.

$$ r_{C}=4\sin\theta ; \; r_{ L}^2=8\cos 2\theta ; $$

$$ A_{Circle} =\frac12\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}   r_C^2 \cdot  d\theta$$

$$A_{Lemniscate} =\frac12\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/4} r_L^2 \cdot d\theta$$

$$ A_{Full Circle}= \pi 2^2 $$

$$ A_{Shaded\,Area} = A_{Full Circle} - 2 (  A_{Circle} + A_{Lemniscate} ) . $$

Comment: The final answer is $\frac{8}{3}\pi+4\sqrt{3}-4$